# Algolia - giving preference to records with a specific value for an attribute

Tags: search, algolia

I have many collections in MongoDB which I have added to the same index, the collections have a `type` attribute which actually contains the name of the collection.

I added a `type` attribute so that I could give custom ranking to results from different collections. But I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Collections: `a, b, c, d, e`

Each collection has a `type` attribute which contains name of the collection.

I want to give searching preference to records in the order `d,c,e,b,a` so if a keyword exists in both `c & a` then result of `c` should be shown first.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was pretty easy, I added an attribute '`priority`' of type `integer` to my collections and used that for custom ranking as it is a number so `asc|desc` worked for it.